# How can I prove this matrix addition invertibility?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Let 2 $v \times v$ invertible matrices $A,B$ such that $A+B$ to be invertible.Show that the matrix $A^{-1}+B^{-1}$ is invertible and $(A^{-1}+B^{-1})^{-1}=A(A+B)^{-1}B=B(A+B)^{-1}A$

My effort :

We know that $A+B$ is invertible.So $$(A+B)(A+B)^{-1}=I$$

I have to show that :

\begin{align*}
AA^{-1}&=I
\\
A^{-1}+B^{-1})(A^{-1}+B^{-1})^{-1}&=I\\
\\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
   A^{-1}+B^{-1})(A^{-1}+B^{-1})^{-1}&=  (A^{-1}+B^{-1}) \left[ B(A+B)^{-1}A \right]\\
   &= A^{-1} \left[ B(A+B)^{-1}A \right] +B^{-1} \left[ B(A+B)^{-1}A \right]\\
   &= B(A+B)^{-1}AA^{-1} + B^{-1}B(A+B)^{-1}A \\
   &= B(A+B)^{-1} +A(A+B)^{-1}\\
   &= (A+B)^{-1}(A+B) \\
   &=I
\end{align*}

Am I correct ? Is there another way ?

Comment: Yes, your proof is more or less the same one as Moritz' proof from the duplicate.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I didn't;t know that sorry.